# Cant Deploy Virtual Assistant Template: 'the term az is not recognised as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: azure, deployment, command-line-interface

I'm a full noob and have been following the GitHub walkthrough to set up a virtual assistant. After much trial and error have built the app in powershell 6, got the azure trial, created a luis, created and now trying to run the recommended deployment, installed yeoman, installed azure Command line CLI, created the bot, and then trying to run the deploy: `.\Deployment\Scripts\deploy.ps1`

But that keeps failing with this:

> az : The term 'az' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
>   Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
>   At C:\Users\Jjc\testbot\Deployment\Scripts\deploy.ps1:73 char:10
>   +     $app = (az ad app create `
>   +             ~~
>   + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (az:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
>
> ! Could not provision Microsoft App Registration automatically. Review the log for more information.
>   ! Log: C:\Users\Jjc\testbot\Deployment\Scripts..\deploy_log.txt

Ive tried 100 ways and help pages today but can't work out why it fails

Ive downloaded the `azure cli`, run `connect-AzAccount` which seemed to work. Then tried `PS C:\Users\Jjc> Update-Module -Name Az` which seemed ok.

I know very little about this whole ecosystem and so after a whole day Im stuck. In some ways it looks to me like the azure connection isn't working as its not finding the az tags, yet the update-module az went through fine.

I am very sure this is me being dumb but ive tried really hard to work out and read up on the context and just cant get it. Help gratefully appreciated

I'm trying to be able to view the bot I built from the GitHub virtual assistant template. It would be good to be able to view it just once :)

Answer (score 0):

I would try the Basic Bot template first, I uploaded the Virtual Assistant template and it didn't work on the cloud, only locally. You can use the Bot Framework Emulator to run the bot locally.
In [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/powershell/powershell) it should recognize all the commands in the deploy script. But it might not be able to register the app in Azure Active Directory, then you'll have to do it mannually at the Azure Portal, get the appId and appPassword from there and add it to the command.

```
.\Deployment\Scripts\deploy.ps1 -appId 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx' -appPassword 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
```